# Perl adding array to hash table

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

When reading an array (actually an array of arrays) from a hash table, there seems to be an extra level in the data structure. I fill the array from a file as such.

```
open(my $fh, '<', $newfile) or next; 
while (my $line = <$fh>)  
{ 
    my @job = split /\s+/, $line;
    push @userjobs, [ @job ];               
}
close ($fh);
```

userjobs has a size of three as expected, from the file, and I add it to the %crontab hash

```
$crontab{$user} = [ @userjobs ];
```

When I attempt to read the user jobs back the size is 1

```
my @temp = $crontab{$user};
```

Looking at Dumper shows an extra level in the hash table value hierarchy.  I can access the hash table through something like $crontab{$user}[0][0]. However, now I want to add a 4th userjob, but I can't access the underlying job array.  Adding `push @temp, [ @newjob ]` adds it to the additional level, but not the job array.  Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Probably you have intended to use `push @userjobs, \@job;` - push into array reference to another array (@job)?

Comment: Show us the Data::Dumper output.

Comment: What is content of your input file? We can not read what is in your mind or files. You should provide sample of input data. Use [Data::Dumper] to investigate structure of `%crontab` you have generated -- post output so we knew what you deal with.

Answer (score 3):

You are adding an array *reference* to the hash:

```
$crontab{$user} = [ @userjobs ];
```

If you want to access the array, you need to *dereference* it:

```
my @temp = @{ $crontab{$user} };
```

Note that this technique potentially implies a hash copy. It might be more efficient to do:

```
$crontab{$user} = \@userjobs;
```

Answer (score 2):

Question is not very clear on desired structure of `%crontab` hash.

Following piece of code is based on best guess that `%crontab` hash will have username as a key and jobs will be stored in array referenced by value associated with the key (username).

*NOTE:* change `$debug = 1` to view `%crontab` hash structure

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use feature 'say';

use Data::Dumper;

my $debug = 0;

my %crontab;

while(<DATA>) {
    my($user,@jobs) = split '\s+';

    push @{$crontab{$user}}, @jobs;
}

say Dumper(\%crontab) if $debug;

while( my($k,$v) = each %crontab ) {
    say 'User: ' . $k . ' => ' . join ' ', @{$v};
}

__DATA__
user1 job1 job2 job3
user2 job1 job2 job3 job4 job5
user3 job1 job2 job3 job4
user4 job1
```

Answer (score 2):

The value of hash elements are scalars, so `$crontab{$user}` is a scalar (containing a reference to an array), so are assigning a single scalar to `@temp`. Replace

```
my @temp = $crontab{$user};

print(Dumper(\@temp));

for (@temp) { ... }
```

with

```
my $temp = $crontab{$user};

print(Dumper($temp));

for (@$temp) { ... }
```

Answer (score 1):

Heh, I think I just answered a similar problem in [How to print the values of array reference in perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60749238/2766176) . You are assigning an array reference to a named array. Since the reference is a scalar (a single value), you get an array of one value that is the reference. Now you have an array of arrays:

```
my @temp = $array_reference; # likely wrong.
```

This is the same as creating a list of one element and assigning that to `@temp`:

```
my @temp = ( [ ... ] );
```

That's where your extra level comes in. The first level is for `@temp`. You access `$temp[0]` to get to the first item in the array, which is the reference. Now, you need to get to elements in that reference, so that's your second level: `$temp[0][0]`.

Since all references are scalars, you likely wanted to assign to a scalar:

```
my $temp = $array_reference;
```

Now that's just the reference with no extra array wrapper around it so you can access its first element as `$temp[0]`. Since all hash values are scalars, that's probably how you want to assign it:

```
my $temp = $crontab{$user};     # whole ref
my $first = $crontab{$user}[0]; # just first element
```